# Upgrade HPE custom image ESXi 6u1 to 6u2

Tags: vmware-esxi, update, upgrade

I would like to upgrade my virtualization host running ESXi 6u1 to 6u2. It runs on HPE server hardware, therefore I use the HPE custom image.
Somehow I have no success to upgrade the machine.
This is what I was doing:

1. Shut down all VMs
2. Enter maintenance mode
3. List profiles: esxcli software sources profile list -d /vmfs/volumes/datastore1/VIB/VMware-ESXi-6.0.0-Update2-3620759-HPE-600.9.5.0.48-Apr2016-depot.zip
4. Update: esxcli software profile update -d /vmfs/volumes/datastore1/VIB/VMware-ESXi-6.0.0-Update2-3620759-HPE-600.9.5.0.48-Apr2016-depot.zip -p

This is how it looks, when I run the upgrade command:

```
[root@esxi:/vmfs/volumes/56855a41-c6c2cdf8-724a-9457a5b4304c/VIB] esxcli software profile update -d /vmfs/volumes/datastore1/VIB/VMware-ESXi-6.0.0-Update2-3620759-HPE-600.9.5.0.48-Apr2016-depot.zip -p HPE-ESXi-6.0.0-Update2-600.9.5.0.48
Update Result
   Message: Host is not changed.
   Reboot Required: false
   VIBs Installed:
   VIBs Removed:
   VIBs Skipped: Avago_bootbank_scsi-mpt2sas_15.10.06.00-1OEM.550.0.0.1331820, BRCM_bootbank_net-tg3_3.137l.v60.1-1OEM.600.0.0.2494585, EMU_bootbank_elxnet_10.7.110.13-1OEM.600.0.0.2768847, EMU_bootbank_ima-be2iscsi_10.7.110.10-1OEM.600.0.0.2159203, EMU_bootbank_lpfc_10.7.110.4-1OEM.600.0.0.2768847, EMU_bootbank_scsi-be2iscsi_10.7.110.10-1OEM.600.0.0.2159203, HPE_bootbank_amsHelper_600.10.4.0-22.2494585, HPE_bootbank_conrep_6.0.0.01-01.00.7.2494585, HPE_bootbank_hpbootcfg_6.0.0.02-02.00.6.2494585, HPE_bootbank_hpe-build_600.9.5.0.48-2494585, HPE_bootbank_hpe-esxi-fc-enablement_600.2.5.20-2494585, HPE_bootbank_hpe-ilo_600.10.0.0.26-1OEM.600.0.0.2494585, HPE_bootbank_hpe-smx-provider_600.03.10.00.13-2768847, HPE_bootbank_hponcfg_6.0.0.04-00.14.4.2494585, HPE_bootbank_hpssacli_2.40.13.0-6.0.0.1854445, HPE_bootbank_hptestevent_6.0.0.01-01.00.5.2494585, Hewlett-Packard_bootbank_char-hpcru_6.0.6.14-1OEM.600.0.0.2159203, Hewlett-Packard_bootbank_hpnmi_600.2.3.14-2159203, Hewlett-Packard_bootbank_scsi-hpdsa_5.5.0.48-1OEM.550.0.0.1331820, Hewlett-Packard_bootbank_scsi-hpsa_6.0.0.116-1OEM.600.0.0.2494585, Hewlett-Packard_bootbank_scsi-hpvsa_5.5.0.100-1OEM.550.0.0.1331820, Intel_bootbank_intelcim-provider_0.5-1.6, Intel_bootbank_net-i40e_1.3.45-1OEM.550.0.0.1331820, Intel_bootbank_net-igb_5.3.1-1OEM.550.0.0.1331820, Intel_bootbank_net-ixgbe_4.1.1.1-1OEM.550.0.0.1331820, MEL_bootbank_nmlx4-core_3.1.0.0-1OEM.600.0.0.2348722, MEL_bootbank_nmlx4-en_3.1.0.0-1OEM.600.0.0.2348722, MEL_bootbank_nmst_4.0.2.1-1OEM.600.0.0.2295424, QLogic_bootbank_misc-cnic-register_1.712.70.v60.1-1OEM.600.0.0.2494585, QLogic_bootbank_net-bnx2_2.2.5k.v60.1-1OEM.600.0.0.2494585, QLogic_bootbank_net-bnx2x_2.712.70.v60.3-1OEM.600.0.0.2494585, QLogic_bootbank_net-cnic_2.712.70.v60.3-1OEM.600.0.0.2494585, QLogic_bootbank_net-nx-nic_6.0.643-1OEM.600.0.0.2494585, QLogic_bootbank_net-qlcnic_6.1.191-1OEM.600.0.0.2494585, QLogic_bootbank_qlnativefc_2.1.30.0-1OEM.600.0.0.2768847, QLogic_bootbank_scsi-bfa_3.2.5.0-1OEM.550.0.0.1331820, QLogic_bootbank_scsi-bnx2fc_1.712.70.v60.5-1OEM.600.0.0.2494585, QLogic_bootbank_scsi-bnx2i_2.712.70.v60.2-1OEM.600.0.0.2494585, QLogic_bootbank_scsi-qla4xxx_644.6.05.0-1OEM.600.0.0.2494585, VMWARE_bootbank_mtip32xx-native_3.8.5-1vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_ata-pata-amd_0.3.10-3vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_ata-pata-atiixp_0.4.6-4vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_ata-pata-cmd64x_0.2.5-3vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_ata-pata-hpt3x2n_0.3.4-3vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_ata-pata-pdc2027x_1.0-3vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_ata-pata-serverworks_0.4.3-3vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_ata-pata-sil680_0.4.8-3vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_ata-pata-via_0.3.3-2vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_block-cciss_3.6.14-10vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_cpu-microcode_6.0.0-0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_ehci-ehci-hcd_1.0-3vmw.600.2.34.3620759, VMware_bootbank_emulex-esx-elxnetcli_10.2.309.6v-0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_esx-base_6.0.0-2.34.3620759, VMware_bootbank_esx-dvfilter-generic-fastpath_6.0.0-0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_esx-tboot_6.0.0-2.34.3620759, VMware_bootbank_esx-ui_1.0.0-3617585, VMware_bootbank_esx-xserver_6.0.0-0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_ima-qla4xxx_2.02.18-1vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_ipmi-ipmi-devintf_39.1-4vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_ipmi-ipmi-msghandler_39.1-4vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_ipmi-ipmi-si-drv_39.1-4vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_lsi-mr3_6.605.08.00-7vmw.600.1.17.3029758, VMware_bootbank_lsi-msgpt3_06.255.12.00-8vmw.600.1.17.3029758, VMware_bootbank_lsu-hp-hpsa-plugin_1.0.0-1vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_lsu-lsi-lsi-mr3-plugin_1.0.0-2vmw.600.0.11.2809209, VMware_bootbank_lsu-lsi-lsi-msgpt3-plugin_1.0.0-1vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_lsu-lsi-megaraid-sas-plugin_1.0.0-2vmw.600.0.11.2809209, VMware_bootbank_lsu-lsi-mpt2sas-plugin_1.0.0-4vmw.600.1.17.3029758, VMware_bootbank_lsu-lsi-mptsas-plugin_1.0.0-1vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_misc-drivers_6.0.0-2.34.3620759, VMware_bootbank_net-e1000_8.0.3.1-5vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_net-e1000e_3.2.2.1-1vmw.600.1.26.3380124, VMware_bootbank_net-enic_2.1.2.38-2vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_net-forcedeth_0.61-2vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_net-mlx4-core_1.9.7.0-1vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_net-mlx4-en_1.9.7.0-1vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_net-vmxnet3_1.1.3.0-3vmw.600.2.34.3620759, VMware_bootbank_nmlx4-rdma_3.0.0.0-1vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_nvme_1.2.0.27-4vmw.550.0.0.1331820, VMware_bootbank_ohci-usb-ohci_1.0-3vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_rste_2.0.2.0088-4vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_sata-ahci_3.0-22vmw.600.2.34.3620759, VMware_bootbank_sata-ata-piix_2.12-10vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_sata-sata-nv_3.5-4vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_sata-sata-promise_2.12-3vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_sata-sata-sil24_1.1-1vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_sata-sata-sil_2.3-4vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_sata-sata-svw_2.3-3vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_scsi-aacraid_1.1.5.1-9vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_scsi-adp94xx_1.0.8.12-6vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_scsi-aic79xx_3.1-5vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_scsi-fnic_1.5.0.45-3vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_scsi-ips_7.12.05-4vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_scsi-megaraid-mbox_2.20.5.1-6vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_scsi-megaraid-sas_6.603.55.00-2vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_scsi-megaraid2_2.00.4-9vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_scsi-mptsas_4.23.01.00-9vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_scsi-mptspi_4.23.01.00-9vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_uhci-usb-uhci_1.0-3vmw.600.0.0.2494585, VMware_bootbank_vsan_6.0.0-2.34.3563498, VMware_bootbank_vsanhealth_6.0.0-3000000.3.0.2.34.3544323, VMware_bootbank_xhci-xhci_1.0-3vmw.600.2.34.3620759, VMware_locker_tools-light_6.0.0-2.34.3620759
[root@esxi:/vmfs/volumes/56855a41-c6c2cdf8-724a-9457a5b4304c/VIB]
```

As you can see, all VIBs have been skipped - I don't know why. I cannot find any relevant logs.

So what's wrong in my process?

Update 1: It is a standalone ESXi, not managed through vCenter.

Any help is appreciated!

cheers

Comment: Is this a standalone host?

Comment: Yes, the ESXi is not managed through vCenter.